# Exporting data to CSV file

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have option to choose agents (1,2,3 or 15). Each of them has same variables and I need to print them into CSV files(depending on number of agents, they may be 2 files or 15 files). What is the best way to do it? I have been looking in dictionary & StackOverflow, but I didn't found this case.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the NetLogo dictionary has a section about input/output. You need the `file-open` to create the file and, most likely, the `file-type` and `file-print` primitives to output the specific values to the file. You need much more detail about your problem to get more specific advice (eg show the code you are currently using, what is it doing wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... it is certainly possible but perhaps not convenient. For example,

```
extensions [csv]

turtles-own [var1 var2 att-file]

to setup
  ca
  crt 15 [setup-att-file]
end

to setup-att-file ;turtle proc
    set att-file (word "turtle" who ".csv")
    carefully [file-delete att-file] []
end

to-report get-att-vals ;turtle proc
  report (list var1 var2)
end

to export-att-vals ;turtle proc
  ask turtles [
    file-open att-file
    file-print csv:to-row get-att-vals
    file-close
  ]
end
```

Comment: So what is the best way to export data(variables) of sellers, which user can set in range of 1- 250 agents. I need to know their variables like price, revenue, totalbudget etc. Thank you for help Seth!  /PS: I was trying to get it done through plot and then export plot, but it's too hard to write i need easier way.

Answer (score 1):

looks I don't need to use csv extension - just need to plot variables and then export plots.

```
ask turtles [
  create-temporary-plot-pen (word who)
  set-plot-pen-color color
  plotxy xcor ticks
]
```

This works pretty much, answer was replied by Seth Tisue in this topic [How to properly plot variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200826/how-to-properly-plot-variables/31209687#31209687)